# How to make table auto resize according to the outside Part area in RCP application by using SWT?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a table in a **Part** area need to be displayed when I open my RCP application, however for now I don't know how to make the table auto resize according to **Part** outside. You can see from my screenshow below which is ugly.

[image]

And following is my source code, I'd really appreciate that if anyone who can show me how to make the table auto resize.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;

import com.hpi.hpdm.console.utils.Device;
import com.hpi.hpdm.console.utils.DeviceRetriever;

public class DeviceListPart {
    private static Table table;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(Composite parent) {

        parent.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        table = new Table(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        FormData fd_table = new FormData();
        fd_table.bottom = new FormAttachment(0, 465);
        fd_table.right = new FormAttachment(0, 620);
        fd_table.top = new FormAttachment(0, 44);
        fd_table.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        table.setLayoutData(fd_table);


        Button btnRetrieve = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);

        FormData fd_btnRetrieve = new FormData();
        fd_btnRetrieve.bottom = new FormAttachment(table, -4);
        fd_btnRetrieve.left = new FormAttachment(table, 0, SWT.LEFT);
        btnRetrieve.setLayoutData(fd_btnRetrieve);
        btnRetrieve.setText("Retrieve");

        Button btnAdd = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);

        FormData fd_btnAdd = new FormData();
        fd_btnAdd.top = new FormAttachment(btnRetrieve, 0, SWT.TOP);
        fd_btnAdd.left = new FormAttachment(btnRetrieve, 6);
        btnAdd.setLayoutData(fd_btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setText("Add");

        Button btnDelete = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_btnDelete = new FormData();
        fd_btnDelete.top = new FormAttachment(btnRetrieve, 0, SWT.TOP);
        fd_btnDelete.left = new FormAttachment(btnAdd, 6);
        btnDelete.setLayoutData(fd_btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setText("Delete");

        String[] titles = { "Device Name", "Description"};
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setText(titles[i]);
            table.getColumn(i).pack();
        }


        for (int i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
            table.getColumn (i).pack ();
        }



    }

    @Focus
    public void onFocus() {
        table.setFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the right and bottom attachments for the table to be 100 percent of the width/height with a small negative offset for any border you want:

```
fd_table.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
fd_table.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
```

Note: It is not a good idea to change the layout of the parent `Composite` passed to the `@PostConstruct` method. Create your own `Composite` inside the parent composite.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works. Could you please show me the right way to create my own `Composite` without breaking the GUI effect I want? I tried `Composite ownComp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE); ownComp.setLayout(new FormLayout());`, it isn't what I want though.

Comment: Why isn't it what you want? Don't forget to change all the remaining references to `parent` to be `ownComp`.